# Is there a way to test a component is part of another component react subtree?

Tags: reactjs

I know i can use `elementA.contains(elementB)` to test if an element B is part of the Dom subtree of an element A.
But when using a portal to display B this wont work anymore as B is not anymore in the Dom Subtree.

Is there any clean way to test that B is in the React subtree of A ?

**Edit**:
codeSandbox example code https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-surf-e1e8by?file=/src/App.js

Click the "open a dialog in portal" and then click the close button.
It will fire the portal click event. I know in this case we could have bound the event with onClick props on the portal markup but this is not the solution i'm looking for. What I'm looking for is a way to test in the event handler that evt.currentTarget.contains(evt.target) as part of its react subtree not dom subtree. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: If you are using a specific testing library, it might be worth adding the relevant tag.

Comment: why not just an id or dummy css class to the components and search for the parent with plain javascript or jquery?

Comment: you could also pass a property "ParentName" and check that to see who the parent is

Comment: Events and Context are preserved across React trees when using portals, so your test could have B fire an event that A has a handler defined for, or A could create a Context that B can be tested to have access to still.

Comment: For a more concrete example we would need to see some implementation details of A and B.

Comment: I can't see how simply knowing that a React element B is a child in the React tree of another element A is useful. What is it that you _actually_ want to test for that depends on this relationship?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, your suggestion would be intereseting, but in my real usecase you don't know what will come through your portal as other devs will inject stuffs in it along the road and I don't want them to specify such thing when sending content to the portal.

Comment: @morganney in the same way I don't want to have other devs to know about a particular context only to send content through a portal

Comment: @jsejcksn I've just added a codesandbox I hope it will be more clear now ( this is just a minimal demo of the problem not the full real case usage)

Answer (score 0):

To borrow the principles of [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/#this-solution), tests should resememble how your software is used, not how it is built.

Unless you are building a library, the question of whether a component is part of another component's subtree probably isn't relevant – that's an implementation detail (which may change at some point!).

In this case, it sounds like you want to ensure that a particular component is clickable.

You could add a check within your event listener to see if the click came from the component in question:

```js
if (evt.currentTarget.querySelector(".dialog") === null) return;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-water-3ddf5p?file=/src/App.js:877-941

Or simply target `.dialog` directly. From the user perspective, does it matter that it is inside the `#portal` element?

Comment: The end user doesn't care, but as you mentioned i'm building a library and already had 2 use cases for such feature. I found a hackish way to do that but I refuse to use it (i'll try to report it there for keeping a trace and education). In the 2 use cases I had, I finally came with more complex solution (at least in a code logic point of view) that I whished. As i'm a curious guy I just want to find out how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Grant here's the crappy solution I came up with for now:

```
    const getFiber = (component) => {
        const fiberKey = Object.keys(component).filter(k=>!!k.match(/reactFiber/))[0]
        return component[fiberKey]
    }
    const isInReactSubTreeOf = (maybeChildElementOrFiber, parentElement) => {
        const childFiber = maybeChildElementOrFiber instanceof HTMLElement ? getFiber(maybeChildElementOrFiber) : maybeChildElementOrFiber
        if (!childFiber.return) { // no more parent exit
            return false
        }
        if(childFiber.return?.stateNode === parentElement ) { // testing parentElement
            return true
        }
        // we continue to walk the tree from parent
        return isInReactSubTreeOf(childFiber.return, parentElement)
    }
```

Then we can do:

```
isInReactSubTreeOf(elementB, elementA)
```

This was interesting to find out but, this used unreliable apis so I was looking for a cleaner way to perform the same thing.

When I say unreliable, it's because it's clearly not intended to be used that way. Future implementation can break this hack without warning, as once again it's not intended to be used that way. This is internal api we should not mess with.